# How to share files between linux and window os from Network sharing

Tags: linux, windows, sharing, samba, file-sharing

I want to copy some files from one computer to another computer using LAN or WiFi.But i am not able to see windows shared drive on Linux network or Linux shared drive on window network.Can anyone suggest me how to configure the network for sharing files between Linux and windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure samba or CIFS. Check the link http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0001.html or http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

i think this problem solved with configuring samba server installing in ur linux system. this is NFT system works in different platforms

Answer (score 0):

**Access Windows file in Linux**

```
Mount –t cifs –o username=YourUserName,password=YourPassword --verbose //WindowsComputerName/Folder /media/Folder
```

1. Don’t input domain name in front of YourUserName.
2. Don’t input space between username and password.
3. You can ignore apostrophe of username.
4. You’d better input –verbose so that you can see detail information after execution.
5. You should create /media/Folder in advance.
6. If it prompts “Permission Denied” after execution, you can read Windows event log to get the root cause!

Refer to: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

**Access Linux file in Windows**

http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/